# You must be from 80 to 300 pixels wide, and 30 to 85 tall

Tags: flutter

I am pretty new in flutter and I am trying to understand the layout constraints according by https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints.

What I do not understand is the following sentence:

> Parent: “You must be from 80 to 300 pixels wide, and 30 to 85 tall.”

that means:

```
minimum width: 80
maximum width: 300

minimum height: 30
maximum height: 85
```

How does the parent can determine the min. max. width and min. max. height? Why is the `minimum width` is `80` and `minimum height` is `30`?

Answer (score 2):

The most common way of defining constraints of a Widget in flutter is:

```
Container (
 constraints: BoxContstraints(
   minWidth:80,
   maxWidth:300,
   minHeight:30,
   maxHeight:85,
 ),
 child: Widget(),
),
```

That way a parent can indeed determine min max of width and height. Of course these values can be whatever you want, even variables. You should take these values as de facto in the tutorial and see if you can understand the logic after that step. If you can, then you'll be able to debug object rendering in UI faster. 
Welcome to flutter :)